# cannot Resolve method newBuilder in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm kind of new in Android development in Android Studio. I tried to put following code in Android Studio. But its showing cannot resolve method newBuilder(). This code is perfectly working in the Eclipse though. I can't find any solution for this problem. I'm implementing UC SDK which is not so popular. So there is not enough documentation is available on the internet about this.

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(mAdListener);
    AdRequest request = AdRequest.newBuilder().pub(PUB).build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);
```

[android studio code snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQabA.png)

Comment: Are you create   `AdView` for `Google play SDK`

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

and

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="bla bla"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```